# How can I load style into head tag after ajax load of partialview in asp .net mvc project?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, stylesheet

I want to change style references inside head tag when partial view is loaded to page with ajax. What is the logical way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For replacing the style-sheet you can remove the existing one add a new one like below.

**Remove existing style-sheet**

```
$("link#mystylesheet").remove();
```

**Add new stylesheet**

```
var link = $("<link>");

link.attr({
        id: 'mystylesheet',
        type: 'text/css',
        rel: 'stylesheet',
        href: '/Content/themes/super/style.css'
});

$("head").append(link);
```

Comment: Thanks, a good approach. If there are image references in stylesheet to be added, do images work(if it was not loaded before)? And, can I choose place inside header to add?

Comment: I tried and all works. Images work, and I can add a specific position inside header.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of your setup, but how about namespaced styling rules? Then after your AJAX load, do something like `$('body').addClass('someAjaxyClassName');`

Comment: I don't need to add class; I need to add stylesheet reference, and I wonder is there a good way to do this. By the way, yes I use jquery